# More than one writes to file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a web application and when the users clicks save, a write to a file should occur. The application is "a football scheduler", thus more than one players can click on the save button at the very same time.

Initially I thought that this would be something rare, but this is not the case, since when the match in announced players rush into, because the match will be full in a short period of time.

What happens if two players press save at the same time? Only the save of one player will take effect and the other one will be lost (and it is not rare that this happens with the last available position and then there is some conflict).

How can I cope with this phenomenon?

// removed code since it wasn't needed

---

I would like to know if this is possible without using a database. So a no answer is also accepted.

Comment: How about using a database instead ?

Comment: I would like to know if this is possible without using a database. :)

Comment: you can make your save append-only, and to access, read from the end of the file to the start until enough you find enough info to fulfill the query. that way, even if both players save at the same time, both data are saved and you can reconcile on-demand. append-only file IO is also extremely fast, even faster than DBs...

Comment: @WesleyMurch: that wouldn't need to be the case if using an append-only file: it's accretive nature means it can be rolled-back to any prior point in time.

Comment: @dandavis I am not sure I follow, can you analyse? Wesley, the saved data are just the name of the players and the date,time and day of the match.

Comment: @G.Samaras: well it's a little complicated, but using append-only is basically like turning your "flat file" into a spreadsheet where each modification adds a row to the end. its also MUCH quicker than re-writing the whole file each time, since only changed bytes are committed and most of the file is un-affected, which avoids the need for locking the file. to read, you grab chucks from the end of the file instead of the whole file. if you need to find fred's score, you loop backwards line-by-line until you find fred, and then you have the latest/current state for that player.

Comment: http://php.net/flock for one. if you have multiple users hammering on that file in parallel, you WILL get data corruption. At least with locking you can keep things down to "one-at-a-time".

Comment: and of course, if this data is not to be archived, then something like APC or redis is far more appropriate and orders of magnitude faster than files or DBs for storing transient state.

Comment: @MarcB, thanks for pointing out that function.  I didn't realize it existed.  I added an example to my answer including flock().

Comment: Smart move @Devon! dandavis interesting approach. Thanks Marc!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suppose you would handle this the same way that a database would.  Add a lock to the file and wait.

Something like:

```
while (file_exists('file.lock')) {
  usleep(10000);
}
touch('file.lock');
...
unlink('file.lock');
```

You may want to add a timeout.  I would think this would be safe enough, but I suppose it is still possible for two users to run this at the EXACT same time.  In that case, you may want to add a check that their content was successfully saved before continuing.

**Update:**  As Marc B pointed out, file locking appears to be included in php, didn't know about this function until he pointed it out [flock()](http://php.net/flock).

```
$fp = fopen("file", "r+");

// try to acquire an exclusive lock, otherwise sleep 10ms before trying again
while (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {  
    usleep(10000);
}

fwrite($fp, "Write something here\n");
fflush($fp);            // flush output before releasing the lock
flock($fp, LOCK_UN);    // release the lock

fclose($fp)
```

This would be similar to the function I wrote above.  Of course don't pay attention to the fwrite, I just copied the example from php.net to show how `flock()` works.

Comment: I do not get it. The file always exists, even there is no match scheduled.

Comment: You create a lock file to signify someone else has the main file open.  You check for that lock file before opening the file.

Comment: it's counter-intuitive that using 4 sync file IOs instead of 1 helps problems associated with file access delay...

Comment: @dandavis Locking is pretty standard when using a filesystem to prevent two users from having the same file open with write privileges.  A DBMS does the same thing but the lock is for a table and it exists in memory which is why it is better for this type of action.  However, the OP didn't want to use a database.  Touching a file is a faster operation which is why it would be beneficial.

Comment: Why to use `r+` since we want only to write to the file? Maybe `c` or `c+` would be better? http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: @G.Samaras You may wish to open it in a different mode, I suggest you only use my example as a reference and not rely on it as written.  I only copied the example from php.net which they appear to always use `r+`.  The only reason I could find was in the comments regarding truncating the file so it doesn't look like this applies to you.

Comment: @G.Samaras.  `r+` and using `ftruncate()` as the example on php.net shows seems to be the way to go if you're looking to completely overwrite the file.  If you are just appending to the file, then you'll probably want to use `a`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to write to the same file at the same time.

You could use a database, which can handle more than one access at the same time. In my opinion this is the best solution for handling and accessing a lot of data!

Or you could store the data in seperate files for seperate users, which are all created in a certain folder, and if there are more files available, save them one after another and delete them afterwards. Then keep on writing in the masterfile until no more files are available. This would be a workaround and I really would not recommend it, but anyways it should work if you really don't want to use a database.

Comment: As you can see in my question, I would like not to use a database.